# Does anybody do $p$-adic Teichmüller theory?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

In "Foundations of $p$-adic Teichmüller theory", Mochizuki describes a theory one of whose goals (according to the author) is to generalize Fuchsian uniformization of Riemann surfaces to the $p$-adic context. A quick glance through this book reveals a lot of new concepts (with fancy names!) introduced by Mochizuki.

The question is: what are some landmark papers in this theory (after this textbook)? Did anybody other than Mochizuki and his postdocs/students make contributions to this theory? A less mathematical question: are there any people in Western Europe/U.S. working on this topic in the present?

For example, while I think that [Jakob Stix](https://arxiv.org/search/math?searchtype=author&query=Stix%2C%20J) is doing some anabelian geometry (and Mochizuki has made major contributions to it), I am not sure if any of his work is specifically building upon "Foundations of $p$-adic Teichmüller theory".

P.S. Not being an inter-universalist, I do not know whether "Foundations of $p$-adic Teichmüller theory" have anything to do with the IUT. The question, however, is not about IUT. To avoid off-topic debate, let us pretend in this thread that IUT papers do not exist.

Comment: I know nothing about the p-adic case (only the classical theory of complex projective structures on Riemann surfaces), but Mathsci net gives a list of 32 papers referring to Mochizuki's book (and not all of these are by Mochizuki himself).

Comment: What did you get wham you looked up who cited the book on MathSciNet, Zentralblatt, and Google Scholar? That's the obvious thing to do.

Comment: @Dirk well, at least MathSciNet is behind a paywall unless you have a good IP address (so I would not say it is "the obvious thing to do"). Google Scholar is entirely free though.

Comment: ZBMath is free and knows 12 citations to the foundations book (but only shows three works without subscription:  https://zbmath.org/?q=rf%3A0969.14013)

Answer (score 2):

From MathSciNet:

MR3905130  Lan, Guitang ;  Sheng, Mao ;  Yang, Yanhong ;  Zuo, Kang . Uniformization of p-adic curves via Higgs–de Rham flows.
 J. Reine Angew. Math.  747  (2019), 63--108.

R3700485  Wakabayashi, Yasuhiro . Duality for dormant opers.
 J. Math. Sci. Univ. Tokyo  24  (2017),  no. 3, 271--320.

MR3658210  Joshi, Kirti . The degree of the dormant operatic locus.
 Int. Math. Res. Not. IMRN  2017,  no. 9, 2599--2613.

MR3615581  Zhao, Yifei . Maximally Frobenius-destabilized vector bundles over smooth algebraic curves.
 Internat. J. Math.  28  (2017),  no. 2, 1750003, 26 pp.

MR3417530  Hoshi, Yuichiro . Nilpotent admissible indigenous bundles via Cartier operators in characteristic three.
 Kodai Math. J.  38  (2015),  no. 3, 690--731.

MR3318144  Joshi, Kirti ;  Pauly, Christian . Hitchin-Mochizuki morphism, opers and Frobenius-destabilized vector bundles over curves.
 Adv. Math.  274  (2015), 39--75.

MR3296806  Gabber, Ofer ;  Gille, Philippe ;  Moret-Bailly, Laurent . Fibrés principaux sur les corps valués henséliens.
(French)  [[Principal bundles over Henselian valued fields]]  Algebr. Geom.  1  (2014),  no. 5, 573--612.

MR3262443  Wakabayashi, Yasuhiro . An explicit formula for the generic number of dormant indigenous bundles.
 Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci.  50  (2014),  no. 3, 383--409.

MR3103899  Bouw, Irene I. ;  Zapponi, Leonardo . Existence of covers with fixed ramification in positive characteristic.
 Int. J. Number Theory  9  (2013),  no. 6, 1475--1489.

MR2680418  Bouw, Irene I. ;  Möller, Martin . Teichmüller curves, triangle groups, and Lyapunov exponents.
 Ann. of Math. (2)  172  (2010),  no. 1, 139--185.

MR2566970  Ducrohet, Laurent . The Frobenius action on rank 2 vector bundles over curves in small genus and small characteristic.
 Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble)  59  (2009),  no. 4, 1641--1669.

MR2518167  Osserman, Brian . Logarithmic connections with vanishing p-curvature.
 J. Pure Appl. Algebra  213  (2009),  no. 9, 1651--1664.

MR2384903  Joshi, Kirti . Two remarks on subvarieties of moduli spaces.
 Internat. J. Math.  19  (2008),  no. 2, 237--243.

MR2365412  Lange, Herbert ;  Pauly, Christian . On Frobenius-destabilized rank-2 vector bundles over curves.
 Comment. Math. Helv.  83  (2008),  no. 1, 179--209.

MR2317114  Osserman, Brian . Mochizuki's crys-stable bundles: a lexicon and applications.
 Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci.  43  (2007),  no. 1, 95--119.

MR2285248  Benedetto, Robert L.  Wandering domains in non-Archimedean polynomial dynamics.
 Bull. London Math. Soc.  38  (2006),  no. 6, 937--950.

MR2266885  Conrad, Brian . Relative ampleness in rigid geometry.
 Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble)  56  (2006),  no. 4, 1049--1126.

MR2255181  Osserman, Brian . The generalized Verschiebung map for curves of genus 2.
 Math. Ann.  336  (2006),  no. 4, 963--986.

MR2231194  Joshi, Kirti ;  Ramanan, S. ;  Xia, Eugene Z. ;  Yu, Jiu-Kang . On vector bundles destabilized by Frobenius pull-back.
 Compos. Math.  142  (2006),  no. 3, 616--630.

MR2223683  Liu, Fu ;  Osserman, Brian . Mochizuki's indigenous bundles and Ehrhart polynomials.
 J. Algebraic Combin.  23  (2006),  no. 2, 125--136.

MR2219211  Bouw, Irene I. ;  Wewers, Stefan . Indigenous bundles with nilpotent p-curvature.
 Int. Math. Res. Not.  2006, Art. ID 89254, 37 pp.

MR2118045  Mochizuki, Shinichi . Categories of log schemes with Archimedean structures.
 J. Math. Kyoto Univ.  44  (2004),  no. 4, 891--909.

MR2095769  Moriwaki, Atsushi . Diophantine geometry viewed from Arakelov geometry [translation of Sūgaku 54 (2002), no. 2, 113–129;  MR1911908].
Sugaku Expositions.
 Sugaku Expositions  17  (2004),  no. 2, 219--234.

MR1859246  Ogus, Arthur . Elliptic crystals and modular motives.
 Adv. Math.  162  (2001),  no. 2, 173--216.

MR1834911  Nakamura, Hiroaki ;  Tamagawa, Akio ;  Mochizuki, Shinichi . The Grothendieck conjecture on the fundamental groups of algebraic curves [translation of Sūgaku 50 (1998), no. 2, 113–129; MR1648427 (2000e:14038)].
Sugaku Expositions.
 Sugaku Expositions  14  (2001),  no. 1, 31--53.

MR1812812  Edixhoven, S. J. ;  Moonen, B. J. J. ;  Oort, F.  Open problems in algebraic geometry.
 Bull. Sci. Math.  125  (2001),  no. 1, 1--22.